# codeigniter why does my get gives me an error

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.6 and this is my code:

```
  public function Get($Table,$where_Query = null,$GroupBy=null,$OrderBy=null,$Limit=null,$SpecificData=null,$OtherTable=null,$Where=null)
      {
        $result;
        if($SpecificData !== null)
          $this->db->select($SpecificData);
        else
          $this->db->select('*');
        if($OtherTable !== null){
          foreach ($OtherTable as $pTable) {
            $this->db->from($pTable);
          }
        } else{
          $this->db->from($Table);
        }
        //where
        if($where_Query !== null)
          $this->db->where($where_Query);
        if($Where !== null){
          foreach ($Where as $value) {
            $this->db->where($value);
          }
        }

        //group by
        if($GroupBy !== null)
          $this->db->group_by($GroupBy);
        //order group_by 
        if($OrderBy !== null)
          $this->db->order_by($OrderBy,'desc');
        // //limit

        if($Limit !== null)
          $result = $this->db->limit($Limit);        
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->db->get_compiled_select());
        echo "</pre>";
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
      }
```

So, when I printed the query that I've been producing, it looks correct for me, however, it gives me an error.

In addition to that, when I removed the line `$this->db->from($table)` and put the `$table` in get [like this `$this->db->get($table)`], it gives me all of my data in database not just the one with the `username = 'pogi' and password = 'pogi'`.

[image: Database Error and Query I've produced]

Comment: Try `$this->db->query()` instead.

Comment: You must use a table. From the error it is mentioned `No tables used`

Comment: For checking the query that I've produced?

Comment: Thank you guys!! I've found out what causes the error, it is the line  echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->db->get_compiled_select());
        echo "</pre>";
when i removed it, my code worked :D